# Collection of objects

Tags: collections, x++, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I want to store list of objects in X++. I've read in msdn that arrays and containers cannot store Objects, so the only option is to make a list of Collection. I have written the following code and tried to use `Collection = new List(Types::AnyType);` and `Collection = new List(Types::Classes);` but both are not working. Please see if I'm making some mistake in the following job.

```
static void TestList(Args _args)
{
    List Collection;
    ListIterator iter;
    anytype iVar, sVar, oVar;

    PlmSizeRange PlmSizeRange;
    ;
    Collection = new List(Types::AnyType);

    iVar = 1;
    sVar = "abc";
    oVar = PlmSizeRange;
    Collection.addEnd(iVar);
    Collection.addEnd(sVar);
    Collection.addEnd(oVar);    

    iter = new ListIterator(Collection);
    while (iter.more())
    {
        info(any2str(iter.value()));
        iter.next();
    }
}
```

Moreover, can't we cast some variable or object into Anytype variable, I read out that typecasting is done automatically this way;

```
anytype iVar;
iVar = 1;
```

But on running it throws an error that expected type was Anytype, but encountered type is int.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Last things first, `anytype` variables takes the type first assigned to it, you cannot change it later:

```
static void Job2(Args _args) 
{
    anytype iVar;
    iVar = 1;             //Works, iVar is now an int!
    iVar = "abc";         //Does not work, as iVar is now bound to int, assigns 0
    info(iVar); 
}
```

Back to your first question, `new List(Types::AnyType)` will never work as the `addEnd` method tests the type of its argument at runtime, and `anytype` variables will have the type of the value assigned to it.

Also `new List(Types::Object)` will only store objects, not simple data types as `int` and `str`.
It may be contrary to your what you (and C#) believe, but simple types are not objects.

What is left? Containers:

```
static void TestList(Args _args)
{
    List collection = new List(Types::Container);
    ListIterator iter;
    int iVar;
    str sVar;
    Object oVar;
    container c;
    ;
    iVar = 1;
    sVar = "abc";
    oVar = new Object();
    collection.addEnd([iVar]);
    collection.addEnd([sVar]);
    collection.addEnd([oVar.toString()]);
    iter = new ListIterator(collection);
    while (iter.more())
    {
        c = iter.value();
        info(conPeek(c,1));
        iter.next();
    }
}
```

Objects do not automatically convert to containers, usually you supply `pack` and `unpack` methods (implementing the interface `SysPackable`). In the above code `toString` is used which is cheating.

On the other hand, I do not see a use case for your request, that Lists should contain any type. It is against its designed purpose, a List contain one and only one type as defined when the [List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/list.aspx) object is created.

Besides lists there are [other collections types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa608508.aspx), maybe a [Struct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/struct.aspx) will suit your needs.

Comment: Comment#1
Getting this exception while running job2...
Error executing code: Wrong type of argument for conversion function.
Stack trace
(C)\Jobs\Job2 - line 6

Comment: @BilalSaeed - Comment out "iVar = 1", and the anytype will be bound to a string and the any2str will work.

Comment: Removed `any2str`, it does not work for an `anytype` bound to an int!